# Angled full width background with wave form?

Tags: css

Can someone tell me what is the best way to deal with angled background with full width?

I want to create something like this:

[image: Angled background]

I tried with the `:after` selector but it's not working the way I want it to.

```
.bg {
    background: #000;
}

.bg:after {
    content:"";
    height: 469px;
    background: url("http://i.imgur.com/SqqtkYk.png");
    display: block;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dxs1pqpu/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you have to give `body, html{margin:0;padding:0}` and give some `position` with some `width:100%`. SEE **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/dxs1pqpu/5/)**.

```
body, html{margin:0; padding:0;}
.bg {
    background: #000;
}

.bg:after {
    content:"";
    height: 469px;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    background: url("http://i.imgur.com/SqqtkYk.png");
    display: block;
    width:100%;
}
```

Comment: @MordFustang is that answer helpful for you?

Comment: Yes this is working, thanks. Also is there any better way to do this? or what is the best practice for making that kind of background

Comment: Well calling the background image using `"pseudo` element this way you can give some blurr effect and can use CSS filters and can make a semi transparent image.

Comment: so it up to totally on your requirement and there is nothing wrong with this approach. Can you accept this answer so this question could be closed.

Comment: your solution is working, but if there is better solution I want to see it :).